# Javascript not redirecting page

Tags: javascript

I have the following html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="buttonClicked.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="confirmChangeId" name="selectionForm" method="POST">
            <input id="btnChange" type="submit" value="Change">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

using the following javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    initFunc();
}

var initFunc = function() {
    var change = document.getElementById("btnChange");
    change.onclick=function() {
        window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
        //alert("change button clicked"); // If this line is uncommented, then the page re-direction does occur
    }
}
```

Using Firefox, when the alert is uncommented in the JS file then the redirection does occur. To throw a further spanner in the works, no redirection occurs whatsoever when using Chrome or Opera. I'm clearly missing something small here, but can't find what it is. Suggestions?

Comment: Tried changing your button type from submit to button? What appears to be happening is that nothing is stopping your form from being submitted.

Comment: Alternatively, prevent the form from being submitted.
change.onclick=function( e ) { e.preventDefault(); //Other stuff }

Comment: Thanks guys. This plus Michaels answer below makes for a much more elegant solution! The alert was only ever thrown in to confirm that something was happening. It was a complete fluke that it actually allowed the page redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the redirection to reliably work, you must add `return false;` at the end of your onlick function.

*Note:* You should really attach event listeners to the objects instead of using the outdated `onclick` property.

```
var change = document.getElementById("btnChange");
change.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops the click from completing
    window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. JS newbie pulling my hair out for far too long trying to get this to work!

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` in your function.otherwaise form being submited before redirect

```
 var initFunc = function() {
 var change = document.getElementById("btnChange");
 change.onclick=function() {
    window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
    return false;
    //alert("change button clicked"); // If this line is uncommented, then the page re-         direction does occur
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work. It is imperative that you add the return false to your onlcik function. You need event listeners.

See below:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    initFunc();
}

var initFunc = function() {
    var change = document.getElementById("btnChange");
change.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops the click from completing
    window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
}, false);
}
</script>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="confirmChangeId" name="selectionForm" method="POST">
            <input id="btnChange" type="submit" value="Change">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```